# Dumb java function + OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv

Guys can you please help me out of this error.
I really don't know whats happening but it has a **NullPointerException** and keeps terminating my program.

I know that in opencv if you use the function `Mat.get(row, col)` will return to a array of double for BGR Color space just like this.

```
double[] value = new double[]({B, G, R});
```

But I got an exception whenever I want to find out whats the value of the array double
could anyone check this out?
here is my function:

```
public Mat defineContour( Mat src, Mat dst )    {
    double[] value;// = new double[]{0, 0, 0};
    double[] s = new double[]{0, 0, 255}, p1, p2, p3;
    for(int i = src.rows(); i > 0; i--) {
        for(int j = 0; j < src.cols(); j++) {
            value = src.get(i, j);
            System.out.println(value[0]);
        }// for j
    }//for i

    return dst;
}//defineContour
```

I only want to check and print the value of value[0] which is a double[] which has three elements. (BGR) so I am expecting that there is a value for the given object.

It keeps terminating the whole program for this exception. Please help!

Comment: Anytime an exception is thrown, post the stacktrace for that exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should indexed from `src.rows()-1` instead of `src.rows()`.
When you refers beyound the actual size of Mat, you got `null` value instead of an array. That makes you `value` equal to `null`, and when you tried to get the first element of value: `value[0]`, `NPE` was thrown.

Comment: Thank you it solved my problem! but I guess i don't have to do the same thing with scr.cols() I think? hehe. can you please explain why do I need to index it from src.rows() -1?

Comment: You are right, i corrected my answer. Because if src.height() equals to 10, it means that there are 10 rows. But they are idexed from 0, to the last one is on 9 index. So `src.get(src.height(), _)` means that you try to get cell beyond the max allowed index.